# Deploying fullstack app with Github Actions (Go + ClojureScript)

Tags: javascript, go, deployment, github-actions, clojurescript

I was able to build both the **JavaScript bundle**, and the **Go binary**. But, I'm currently unable, due to lack of knowledge, to make the Go server run for the backend, and to display the `public/index.html` as the entry for the front-end.

How could I accomplish that, adding to the existing **yaml** file?

The repository: https://github.com/BuddhiLW/free-riding.
The yaml file: https://github.com/BuddhiLW/free-riding/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml

Current state of the Yaml file:

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name: Run install
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v4
        with:
          cmd: install # will run `yarn install` command

      - name: Install Lynx
        uses: awalsh128/cache-apt-pkgs-action@latest
        with:
          packages: lynx
          version: 1.0

      - name: Prepare java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: "zulu"
          java-version: "17"

      - name: Install clojure tools
        uses: DeLaGuardo/setup-clojure@11.0
        with:
          # Install just one or all simultaneously
          # The value must indicate a particular version of the tool, or use 'latest'
          # to always provision the latest version
          cli: latest # Clojure CLI based on tools.deps

      - name: Generate js bundle
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v4
        with:
          cmd: run build

  golang-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go: ["1.20.3"]
    name: Go ${{ matrix.go }} sample
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: ${{ matrix.go }}
      - run: |
          go build
```

Current status of the build process:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Where are you trying to deploy the software to? You cannot run a go server in a pipeline to serve a website for production purposes (for one, after an hour it's gone). Since you seem to use go only to run a server, I would maybe try to deploy somewhere else? For example, Google Firebase (to serve static files, like the compiled cljs)?

For Firebase looks like this:

Make an account add https://firebase.google.com/ and a project + token.

`firebase.json`

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "resources/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Run `npm i firebase` to install firebase in `package.json`.

Add an action to deploy to Firebase on pushes to main/master:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on push to master
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  test_build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Test
      run: make test
    - name: Build
      run: make prod
    - name: Deploy
      uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
      with:
        args: deploy --only hosting
      env:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Add FIREBASE_TOKEN in a GitHub secret.

For serving static files somewhere else than Firebase I would advise using the web server NGINX. Make an NGINX Docker container and host that container somewhere (e.g. a cloud provider). Dockerfile will look something like this:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.23
COPY resources/public /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/default.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
CMD nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```